# Switch between fake and real api depending on environment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4.1.4, Ruby 2.1.1

So, we have a rails app that needs to hit an external API. We can't run the other app locally right now to make this easier. We are using VCR for writing tests, but in development we created a FakeMyModel class to act like the api, which we have been gradually replacing with MyModel which calls the real api. But in development it would be nice to keep using FakeMyModel, and then have Production use MyModel. Here is the best solution we have so far:

```
# Settings.yml
api:
  model_name: MyModel

# DevelopmentSettings.yml
api:
  model_name: FakeMyModel

# config/initializers/local_apis.rb
Api = Settings.api.model_name.constantize

# app/controllers/some_controller.rb
Api.my_method

# models/my_model.rb
class MyModel
  def my_method
    # Api call here
  end
end

# models/fake_my_model.rb
class FakeMyModel
  def my_method
    { some: 'default_data' }
  end
end
```

This actually works pretty well, except sometimes we get this error:

> ArgumentError - A copy of MyModel has been removed from the module tree but is still active!:

My understanding is because we are initializing our class in config it is not reloaded during development. But within the class itself we call methods inside of it, and since the class is actually in the models folder it is dynamically reloaded in development, and causes this issue. The only solution I have seen for this is to not put code like this in places that don't dynamically reload (like lib, in this case config).

So how can I do this? How can I have a fake and real api class that is called dependent on env, without wrapping every call in a check for env?

Comment: I think I am going to try just making a class in models that does the env check.

Comment: So it's a problem if your local calls the real api? Does the api have environments? Why change the model, when what you really are changing is the data.

Comment: I probably wasn't quite clear on this - we have an external environment that is run like production which we use for testing against locally sometimes. So, in this specific case I am basically running a development server but it is running the real api. The issue is in the way rails doesn't like using lib etc for the on-the-fly reloading that dev env does. But I think a simple class that checks env might not be too intrusive and then I can just call that.

Comment: Ah I see. I use the test env for that. In my config the test env just inherits from prod. Only problem is I have to be careful about creations.